# Getting: Uncaught TypeError: Invalid template!...in mustache.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, mustache

I have been trying to implement external templates, but to no avail.
This is the full error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Invalid template! Template should be a "string" but "undefined" was given as the first argument for mustache#render(template, view, partials)`

I am using `browserify-shim` for some other dependencies, but they work perfectly, and I am not getting errors (from that task) from the terminal. It's just the external template loading which is giving me problems.

```
function templateLoader(e) {
        var doc = document,
            event = EventUtility.getEvent(e),
            target = EventUtility.getTarget(event);
            $("body").load("templates/index.html #overlay", function() {
                var temp1 = $('#overlay').html();
                var output = Mustache.render(temp1);
                $("body").html(output);
            });

    }

var flimFlam = document.getElementById('Container');
EventUtility.addHandler(flimFlam, 'click', templateLoader);
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to put everything in

```
$(document).ready(function(){


});
```

I had the same error and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes this worked, my code was in windows.onload method. And I moved now in document.ready.

Answer (score 1):

because your Mustache template is probably nested in the rendering template. separate them and this error should go away.